# xapool connection timed out

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm using xapool (org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardXAPoolDataSource) with Spring and JPA and I'm getting connection timed out errors. I found the "checkLevelObject" setting, but it doesn't seem to have helped. Should that have fixed it? Are there other setting that I could use to test the connections and have them replaced without impacting the application?

Comment: Which settings did you use for the checkObjectLevel?

Comment: <property name="checkLevelObject" value="2"/>
        <property name="jdbcTestStmt" value="select 1 from dual"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that xapool is a dead project. It is at 1.6beta and hasn't been updated since Dec 2006. I switched my pool to C3P0 and everything works properly now.

Comment: BTW, I had problems with c3p0 as well. It didn't do transactions properly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977366/spring-transactional-cpool-which-one-do-i-use/2002505#2002505 for full instructions on how I did it.