# Spring transaction manager error: Transaction MARKED_FOR_JOINED after isOpen() call

Tags: spring, transactions

What does the following error message mean? Googling for MARKED_FOR_JOINED doesn't return any useful information.

```
ERROR org.hibernate.AssertionFailure.<init>(AssertionFailure.java:47): an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Transaction MARKED_FOR_JOINED after isOpen() call
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:434)
    at $Proxy30.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:195)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:175)
    at $Proxy31.createNativeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.ipass.rbac.svc.FooTst.insertFoo(FooTst.java:20)
    at com.ipass.rbac.svc.FooTst$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7c736518.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
    at com.ipass.rbac.svc.FooTst$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$da856476.insertFoo(<generated>)
    at com.ipass.rbac.svc.SingleTst.testFoo(SingleTst.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringTestMethod.invoke(SpringTestMethod.java:160)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(SpringMethodRoadie.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$RunBeforesThenTestThenAfters.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:333)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:197)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:160)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

The error message occurs when I do the following:

```
@Transactional
public void insertFoo() {
    em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO Foo (id) VALUES (:id)")
        .setParameter("id", System.currentTimeMillis() % Integer.MAX_VALUE )
        .executeUpdate();
}
```

I'm using spring with hibernate as the jpa provider. I'm trying to do a simple transaction using the Bitronix connection pool and transaction manager. The exact same error occurs when I switch from the Bitronix transaction manager to the Atomikos transaction manager. The error doesn't occur when using jotm. But then jotm doesn't seem to do anything at all for me when it comes to having actual transactions.

Here is the bitronix transaction manager configuration:

```
<bean id="btmConfig" factory-method="getConfiguration"
    class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices">
    <property name="serverId" value="spring-btm" />
    <property name="journal" value="null" />
</bean>
<bean id="btmManager" factory-method="getTransactionManager"
    class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices" depends-on="btmConfig"
    destroy-method="shutdown" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="btmManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="btmManager" />
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: This is the second hit on google, and it looks useful to me: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=61273

Comment: Btw, why JTATransactionManager ? Do you really need it?

Comment: @skaffman, the problem with that thread was the solution involved the enhydra xapool which is no good. It's a terrible pool that caused us a variety of problems. It's also a dead project (not updated for years). However, I eventually figured out (I think) that this was caused by an incorrect value for the "hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" property in the entity manager factory declaration int he application context. I'll post the whole solution I came up with as soon as I get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused because I was using enhydra xapool as my connection pool. I eventually got things working by using the Bitronix pool instead. See [spring transactional cpool. Which one do I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977366/spring-transactional-cpool-which-one-do-i-use/2002505#2002505) for full instructions on how I did it.