# Is it possible to use bitronix PoolingDataSource without BTM?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, bitronix

Is it possible to use `bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource` *without* using bitronix transaction manager and using standalone [JBossTS](http://www.jboss.org/jbosstm) instead?

For database access I use Hibernate, with transaction demarcation done with Spring's `@Transactional` annotation (or Spring's `TransactionTemplate` which has similar implementation). `PoolingDataSource` and standalone JBossTS is used in tests, however I'd like not to abandon db connection pooling.

If it's not possible, what other pooling data source will fit here? [Some other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977366/spring-transactional-cpool-which-one-do-i-use) suggests c3p0 is not an option. Is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible and it's also not possible to switch XA pools between transaction managers simply because there is no standard defining the communication between the transaction manager and the JDBC connection pool. At least that's the short story, the long one is here: http://blog.bitronix.be/2011/02/why-we-need-jta-2-0/

AFAIK in the JBossTS case your only options are to use the JBossAS connection pool but that would not be a minor achievement as it requires at least a JCA runtime, but certainly more.

I'm afraid the only realistic options are to use all of BTM or JBossTS without connection pooling or JBossTS with pooling but inside JBossAS.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I thought that pooling can be done transparently in the data source (e.g. on `close` connection is returned to pool instead of being terminated). Thus, if any plain `DataSource` could be used by the given transaction manager, so should be such transparently-pooling DS.

Comment: BTW, for example `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource` is an `javax.sql.javax.sql.XADataSource` and is also a `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` (both interfaces are present since Java 1.4 i think).